# Creating a nested list with list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-lists

Basically, I want to group items in a list. For example:

1. For `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, I want `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`
2. For `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, I want `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]`

I know how to unnest nested lists, but I have no idea how to create a nested list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range) and output slices of `3`:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]

>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Range takes three arguments where first one is start of range, second is the end and third is step. If you're using Python 2 use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it in this way:

```
target = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
n = 3
print([target[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(target), n)])
```

You could change the size of the sublist by changing the n. But in the above code, I use the target twice, I hope to find a way use the target once.